# text editor in Notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++

I have multiple ascii files(each of size of 21 MB) of a model output. These files are supposed to contain the water depth along the river channel and floodplain. It should contain either -9999.0 or the water depths such as 0.286350857461523, 0.011189999598471 or 1.61005678663024 and so on. However, files are corrupt and could not be converted into raster in Arcmap since they have an additional very small values such as 9.99984780443711E-06, 9.99965258958573E-06, and 1.00E-05. And these numbers are all across the file. 
Could anybody tell me how can I identify and replace these values by -9999.0 using Notepad++ or in  Excel. Any  comments would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Why have you included the `microsoft-excel` tag? Is this a question about Notepad++ or Excel?

Comment: [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
 - [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
 - [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
 - [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
 - [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
 - [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: Use "Find and Replace command" , will help you to find 9.99984780443711E-06  & replace with -9999.0 .

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\d+\.\d+E-\d+`
- Replace with: `-9999.0`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\d+     : 1 or more digits
\.      : a dot
\d+     : 1 or more digits
E-\d+   : E- followed by  1 or more digits
```

**Result for example numbers given:**

```
-9999.0
0.286350857461523
0.011189999598471
1.61005678663024
-9999.0
-9999.0
-9999.0
```

Comment: @DeepaGurung: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @DeepaGurung: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers